# Azure App Service Firewall is blocking connection used on a Web Job App that sends and receive XML

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure App Service problem. I'm trying to deploy a WebJob application that sends and receives an XML file.
In localhost environment, this works fine. The problem is when I execute the job from Azure App Service. It seems that the Azure App Service Firewall is blocking the connection, because the Web Job App returns a log message saying "Could not connect to the host". To verify this, I tried to "tcpping" the host, but there was a timed out connection response.

```
D:\home> tcpping maullin.sii.cl
Connection attempt failed: Connection timed out.
Connection attempt failed: Connection timed out.
Connection attempt failed: Connection timed out.
Connection attempt failed: Connection timed out.
```

If i try this in localhost environment, there is no problem and I receive all responses correctly.

The url server I'm trying to send the "XML" file is

```
maullin.sii.cl
```

I researched how to "allow" http traffic (inbound/outbound configuration) in Azure App Service, but it seems that this feature doesn't exist and it is only enabled in Azure Cloud Service.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you very much

G.R

Comment: Can you check that `maullin.sii.cl` does not have a firewall rule blocking the request. Outbound requests that are initiated from Azure App Service won't come from the same service IP address. So may be blocked at `maullin.sii.cl`.

Comment: @BernieWhite unfortunately, I cant check if `maullin.sii.cl` is blocking the request, but it suppose that it isn't, because if I send the XML using a procedure, triggered  by a button in the Web App, it works correctly. The problem is when i try to send the XML using a Web Job App, that, as far as i know, it has a different protocol than Web App. 
PS: Please correct me if im wrong.

Thank you very much!